# XNA Graphics Device Extension

Tags: c#, xna

I have a class that derives from XNA's GraphicsDevice, and i want to use it in my game. However, i can't quite figure out what i'm supposed to do to make this new graphics device replace the old one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can subclass the GraphicsDeviceManager class, which would give you access to the GraphicsDeviceManager's GraphicsDevice class, which is publicly get-only. Here's an example MSDN article about subclassing the GraphicsDeviceManager class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195022.aspx

Comment: Hmm that might help. I'll do some more research. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the winforms sample to show how to manually create a graphics device and what settings you need to set:
http://creators.xna.com/en-us/sample/winforms_series1

Comment: Um, i dont think that helps. i want to know how i might go about creating an extended game class that replaces the graphics device with my extended one. Thanks anyway though